# How to search for a string from multiple files using awk?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have multiple files containing contents in the format as the example below.
the search works for "doe" only but when i try to search "jhon doe" it displays an error,

how can i fix this problem?

1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt ....

1.txt contains

```
Author:jhon doe
Title:book
pages:232
```

```
awk -v var=$string -F ":" '($1~/Author/ && $2 == var) {print FILENAME;}' $BOOK  > temp
test=$( awk 'NR' temp )
cat $test
```

Comment: `var="$string"`?

Comment: @MikiyasMohammed: And, why do you say _multiple files_? I see only one file in your code, `$BOOK`. And of course you should write `"$BOOK"`, in case the file name contains spaces.